# Create example frame

Tags: boxes, examples

[image]
How to create this type of example box? Thank you!

Comment: with `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`.

Comment: I would say: Typical `tcolorbox` environment...

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is the usage of `tcolorbox` like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\myexample}[2]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,title={Example: #1}]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\myexample{test}{This is just a test}
\end{document}
```

[image: The result of above code]

To get something which looks more like the example image provided (thanks to Christian Hupfer) you could use:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\newcommand{\myexample}[2]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=black!5!white,colframe=black,sharp corners,title={Example: #1}]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\myexample{test}{This is just a test}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: result of second code snippet]

Comment: With `skins` library, the `enhanced` and `sharp corners, it would even look more like the example in the O.P. screen shot

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I never used sharp corners, thanks for the tip. I don't think OP needs something that looks just like the example because the question was how to create this type of boxes. Feedback from OP might help here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've added the changes you suggested in a second code snippet.

Comment: @Duy if this answer satisfies your needs you should accept it.

Comment: @skillmon I use 
\documentclass{dmathesis} so it can not run the code. It appears "Can be only used in preamble". Could you help me fix it?

Comment: @Duy You have to put the `\usepackage`, `\tcbuselibrary` and `\newcommand{\myexample}` in your preamble (before `\begin{document}`) and use `\myexample` only after `\begin{document}`. This way it should work.

Comment: @skillmon It works now. However, I meet another problem that the frame moves to the next page of the paper, although there is a space that may fit the frame

Comment: @Duy you can put a `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` in your preamble and insert a `breakable` in the brackets in the line `\begin{tcolorbox}[...]` in the definition of `\myexample`. This way, the boxes might get splitted, so the top half can be shown on the bottom of the first page and the lower half on the top of the following. You can control the breaking with `lines before break=<number>` also inside of the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use a table to do something like this...

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \begin{tabular}{|cp{5in}c|}
    \hline
\cellcolor{black!100}&\multicolumn{1}{p{5in}}{\cellcolor{black!100}{\color{white}\Large{Some Title Here...}}}&\cellcolor{black!100}\\\hline
         &\vskip .01in \lipsum[1]&
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

Comment: Why do you define more columns than necessary? If you just want extra space you can get that using: `\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{1em}}p{5in}@{\hspace{1em}}|}`

Comment: @Skillmon You are quite right, except that in this case doing that results in the top cell having white strips on both sides. Where it should be black.

Comment: I just realised that. There might be a hacky way to get those, though :)